# Copy files to other LAN computers, and create log files for failed computers

Tags: networking, command-line, cmd.exe, copy

I want to create a command to copy files to the computers in the list and create a log file to know which machine copy failed.

```
for /f %a in (list.txt) do copy /y \\server\test\file \\%a\\c$\Intel 1> myoutput.txt 2>&1
```

My copy was successful, but the log output failed.
Hope everyone will support me

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting handles in incorrect streams:

```
for /f %a in (list.txt) do copy /y \\server\test\file \\%a\\c$\Intel 1> myoutput.txt 2>nul
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it still failed to output the error hostname (no copy).